# RDLC Report with subquery dataset

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I am new to ASP. I need help in creating a report. I have an SQL query

```
SELECT StudentID, StudentName, SectionID, ExamID, SubjectID, Subject, Marks, TotalMarks
, Percentage, Grade, (SELECT MAX(Marks) AS Exp1 
FROM tbl_Result 
WHERE (SectionID = @SectionID) 
  AND (SubjectID = view_StudentResult.SubjectID)) AS SubjectToper 
  FROM view_StudentResult WHERE (StudentID = @StudentID)
```

When I display it in report, all other fields are populated as desired but `SubjectToper` field is shown blank. Can someone help in doing this in an elegant way?

Comment: If you run this query in the SSMS, will you get the correct result? With the parameters set to real values, of course.

Comment: Yes it gives correct result in SSMS but in RDLC it shows `subjectToper` field blank.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try populating that field with `Exp1`.</strike>

You are giving the whole sub-query the alias `SubjectToper`, but the actual selection is given the alias `Exp1`.

Check out [this explanation of sub queries](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery).
Especially the last example where they assign a sub query to a value. Maybe that will work?

Your SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT StudentID, StudentName, SectionID, ExamID, SubjectID, Subject, Marks, TotalMarks, Percentage, Grade, 
    SubjectToper = (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM tbl_Result 
    WHERE (SectionID = @SectionID) AND (SubjectID = view_StudentResult.SubjectID)) 
FROM view_StudentResult WHERE (StudentID = @StudentID)
```

Notice I removed the aliases and assigned the sub query to SubjectToper.

I hope this works, otherwise I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Updated my original comment with another idea you can try.

Comment: Still same result :( anyways thank you for your time. Hope to get help from someone.